# Does professional edition Support Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, professional-edition

Is it possible to create Sandbox for PE. I think its not, but just want to double check

Comment: If you need to check for features being available in particular editions, use the Full Edition Comparison Chart : http://www.sfdcstatic.com/uk/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

Answer (score 5):

**No**, as mentioned at the top of the [Sandbox Overview](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=create%5ftest%5finstance.htm&language=en%5fUS) in the documentation:

> Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Database.com
>   Editions

Comment: Guddan: on any of your own questions you can mark the answer that helped you most as so by clicking the (V) button on the left of it. That will indicate to other users that your question has been answered to your satisfaction and reward the poster with a little bit of reputation.

Answer (score 3):

From Summer 16 , You can have 10 Developer Sandbox for Professional edition

Comment: Can you cite a reference for that date?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Dev Pro sandbox for Professional Edition. The link from Bob's comment above show's the sandbox versions available in each Salesforce edition.

[Salesforce Edition Comparison - UK](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/uk/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf)